# Centering element on animation

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a simple app that moves a circle inside a selected square, first you have to choose the circle you need to move and choose the square where it should be, moving of element is ok, my problem is, the element is not centered while its doing the animation even after the animation.

Hope you help me.

Thanks.

```js
var selectedCircle = null;

$(".circle").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected').animate({ top: 0, left: 0 });
    selectedCircle = $(this);
});

$(".container .square").click(function() {
  if (selectedCircle) {
    var selectedSquare = $(this);
    selectedSquare.addClass("selected");
    // 2.5 is for centering the circle in the square : width/height of square - width/height of circle / 2
    // => (50 - 45) / 2
    selectedCircle.animate({
      top: selectedSquare.offset().top - selectedCircle.offset().top + 2.5,      
      left: selectedSquare.offset().left - selectedCircle.offset().left + 2.5
    }, 1200);
  }
  selectedCircle = null;
});
```

```css
.container{
  height: 200px;
  width: 550px;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
.round{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}
.square{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #f60;
  position: relative;
}
.square:nth-child(2){
   width: 65px;
}
.square:nth-child(3){
   width: 75px;
}
.square:nth-child(4){
   width: 85px;
}
.square:nth-child(5){
   width: 95px;
}
.square:nth-child(6){
   width: 105px;
}
.square:nth-child(7){
   width: 115px;
}
.square:nth-child(8){
   width: 125px;
}
.square .circle{
    position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.circle{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.circle span{
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.circle.selected{
  background-color: #FFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="box">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
 <div class="round">
   <div class="circle">
     <span>1</span>
   </div>
   <div class="circle">
     <span>2</span>
   </div>
   <div class="circle">
     <span>3</span>
   </div>
   <div class="circle">
     <span>4</span>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the correct calculation commented in your code:

```
width/height of square - width/height of circle / 2
```

You just need to perform that calculation instead of hard-coding `2.5`:

```
var xOffset = (selectedSquare.width() - selectedCircle.width()) / 2;
var yOffset = (selectedSquare.height() - selectedCircle.height()) / 2;
```

```js
var selectedCircle = null;

$(".circle").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected').animate({ top: 0, left: 0 });
    selectedCircle = $(this);
});

$(".container .square").click(function() {
  if (selectedCircle) {
    var selectedSquare = $(this);
    selectedSquare.addClass("selected");

    var xOffset = (selectedSquare.width() - selectedCircle.width()) / 2;
    var yOffset = (selectedSquare.height() - selectedCircle.height()) / 2;

    selectedCircle.animate({
      top: selectedSquare.offset().top - selectedCircle.offset().top + yOffset,      
      left: selectedSquare.offset().left - selectedCircle.offset().left + xOffset
    }, 1200);
  }
  selectedCircle = null;
});
```

```css
.container{
  height: 200px;
  width: 550px;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
.round{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}
.square{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #f60;
  position: relative;
}
.square:nth-child(2){
   width: 65px;
}
.square:nth-child(3){
   width: 75px;
}
.square:nth-child(4){
   width: 85px;
}
.square:nth-child(5){
   width: 95px;
}
.square:nth-child(6){
   width: 105px;
}
.square:nth-child(7){
   width: 115px;
}
.square:nth-child(8){
   width: 125px;
}
.square .circle{
    position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.circle{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.circle span{
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.circle.selected{
  background-color: #FFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="box">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
 <div class="round">
   <div class="circle">
     <span>1</span>
   </div>
   <div class="circle">
     <span>2</span>
   </div>
   <div class="circle">
     <span>3</span>
   </div>
   <div class="circle">
     <span>4</span>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi sir, can you help me on this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435221/make-clone-on-animation)