# Clone selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working a simple app that move an element inside an element.
The code is working fine, I just want to make a clone of the circles so that I can place same element on different boxes.

I tried to add this line

`$( selectedChip ).clone().after( selectedChip );`

so that every time I click on the squares the clone element will be inserted and the original stays.

Hope you help me.

thanks.

```js
var selectedCircle = null;

$(".circle").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected').animate({ top: 0, left: 0 });
    selectedCircle = $(this);
});

$(".container .square").click(function() {
  // $( selectedChip ).clone().after( selectedChip );
  if (selectedCircle) {
    var selectedSquare = $(this);
    selectedSquare.addClass("selected");

    var xOffset = (selectedSquare.width() - selectedCircle.width()) / 2;
    var yOffset = (selectedSquare.height() - selectedCircle.height()) / 2;

    selectedCircle.animate({
      top: selectedSquare.offset().top - selectedCircle.offset().top + yOffset,      
      left: selectedSquare.offset().left - selectedCircle.offset().left + xOffset
    }, 1200);
  }
});
```

```css
.container{
  height: 200px;
  width: 550px;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
.round{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}
.square{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #f60;
  position: relative;
}
.square:nth-child(2){
   width: 65px;
}
.square:nth-child(3){
   width: 75px;
}
.square:nth-child(4){
   width: 85px;
}
.square:nth-child(5){
   width: 95px;
}
.square:nth-child(6){
   width: 105px;
}
.square:nth-child(7){
   width: 115px;
}
.square:nth-child(8){
   width: 125px;
}
.square .circle{
    position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.circle{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.circle span{
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.circle.selected{
  background-color: #FFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="box">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
 <div class="round">
   <div class="circle">
     <span>1</span>
   </div>
   <div class="circle">
     <span>2</span>
   </div>
   <div class="circle">
     <span>3</span>
   </div>
   <div class="circle">
     <span>4</span>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var selectedCircle = null;

$(".circle").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().siblings('.clone').remove();
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected').animate({
    top: 0,
    left: 0
  });
  selectedCircle = $(this);
});

$(".container .square").click(function() {

  if (selectedCircle) {
    var selectedSquare = $(this);
    debugger;
    var selectedCircleClone = selectedCircle.clone().addClass("clone");
    selectedCircle.after(selectedCircleClone);

    selectedSquare.addClass("selected");

    var xOffset = (selectedSquare.width() - selectedCircleClone.width()) / 2;
    var yOffset = (selectedSquare.height() - selectedCircleClone.height()) / 2;

    selectedCircleClone.animate({
      top: selectedSquare.offset().top - selectedCircleClone.offset().top + yOffset,
      left: selectedSquare.offset().left - selectedCircleClone.offset().left + xOffset
    }, 1200);
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 550px;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}

.round {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.square {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #f60;
  position: relative;
}

.square:nth-child(2) {
  width: 65px;
}

.square:nth-child(3) {
  width: 75px;
}

.square:nth-child(4) {
  width: 85px;
}

.square:nth-child(5) {
  width: 95px;
}

.square:nth-child(6) {
  width: 105px;
}

.square:nth-child(7) {
  width: 115px;
}

.square:nth-child(8) {
  width: 125px;
}

.square .circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.circle {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.circle span {
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.circle.selected {
  background-color: #FFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="round">
    <div class="circle">
      <span>1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
      <span>2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
      <span>3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
      <span>4</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please consider adding some description of the issue and your solution. As of right now, your answer is a game of spot-the-difference.

Answer (score 0):

`$( selectedChip ).clone().after( selectedChip );` does the following:

1. Select `selectedChip`
2. `clone`s it.
3. appends `selectChip` right after the clone.

At no point is the cloned object output to the page.

Keep in mind that [`clone`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) returns a new jQuery object, but doesn't put it anywhere on the DOM.

A quick fix would be:

```
//Copy the selected chip.
$copy = $(selectedChip).clone();
//Append the copy to the DOM right after the selected chip.
$(selectedChip).after($copy);
//If you're into one liners:
$(selectedChip).after($(selectedChip).clone());
```

See also: [jQuery duplicate DIV into another DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068047/jquery-duplicate-div-into-another-div)